# Copy excel file with macro and data connections

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I need copy an excel .xlsm file to different path.  I know the `shutil.copy_file()` will not work because it cannot preserve VBA macro.

I use `openpyxl` like following:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(templateNm, read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
```

The problem is my workbook has some Data Connections (connected to OLAP server), after the file copied, all data connections are lost.  Does `openpyxl` have other options to keep the data connections?

Or I need to use other package to copy the excel file?(I need to preserve both VBA macro and data connections inside .xlsm file).

Comment: I would expect `copy_file()` to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! Charlie.  copy_file() works fine.